# Delphi ESR 2.5 - Python code to start

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all

I have just got a new Delphi ESR 2.5 Radar.
It will be great you can point me to some basic python scripts to get started with the sensor.

My setup uses [Kvaser Leaf](https://www.kvaser.com/product/kvaser-leaf-light-hs-v2/) to communicate with [Delphi ESR 2.5](https://autonomoustuff.com/product/delphi-esr-2-5-24v/) on Ubuntu 18.04

Thanks for the help in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/324233/delphi-esr-2.5---python-code-to-start/) by [Asit](https://answers.ros.org/users/40023/asit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-05-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-29**:
Can you clarify how this is related to ROS?

**Comment by [Asit](https://answers.ros.org/users/40023/asit/) on 2019-05-30**:
Get the python basic would allow me to plug this script into ROS and ROS2...

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-30**:
That makes sense, but at this point your question is about basic interaction with your hardware and the SDK provided by kvaser. That is not a ROS question and would be better asked on a different forum.

**Comment by [Asit](https://answers.ros.org/users/40023/asit/) on 2019-05-30**:
Edited it to fit the forum topic... Hope, now it can stay live...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. Connect your Kvaser adapter to usb
2. Make sure it's visible: **ifconig -a** should show can0 (or other canX interface)
3. Up your can interface as explained here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SocketCAN#Usage
4. Run **sudo apt install can-utils** (https://github.com/linux-can/can-utils)
5. Make sure you see the data coming on your can interface **cansniffer -f can0**
6. Use socketcan_bridge (http://wiki.ros.org/socketcan_bridge) to publish CAN data from can0 to ROS topic
7. Create regular python node listening to topic published by socketcan_bridge and processed received radar data

---

Originally posted by [mch](https://answers.ros.org/users/31598/mch/) with karma: 46 on 2019-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-08**:\

> Create regular python node listening to topic published by socketcan_bridge and processed received radar data

something to consider: if you transparently bridge CAN msgs into your ROS nodegraph, any node you write that subscribes to the CAN messages is *immediately* completely coupled to your radar sensor.

I would seriously recommend not doing that. Instead, use ROS messages: either existing ones or create a new one. Not to hold a bare CAN message, but to correctly encode the semantics and content of what "a radar message" would be.